# Is a product nowhere dense?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Haworth1977, *Baire spaces*.

On page 7 the authors say

> ...the finite product of subsets is nowhere dense iff at least one of the subsets is itself nowhere dense. However, this is not necessarily true for infinite product

and they give an example of countable product that is nowhere dense but every component is somewhere dense. Later they state the following proposition

> For each $\alpha \in A$ let $N_\alpha$ be a subset of the space $X_\alpha$. Then, $\prod_{\alpha\in A}N_\alpha$ is nowhere dense in $\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$  iff for some $\beta\in A$, $N_\beta$ is nowhere dense in $X_\beta$ or $\text{cl}N_\alpha\ne X_\alpha$ for infinitely many $\alpha\in A$.

I must miss something because to me the proposition says exactly the contrary of the previous comment.

If someone has the book Kuratowski *Topologie I* (1958, 4th ed., I assume written in French) the proposition above corresponds to some proposition on page 154 of the given edition of Kuratowski, and it would be interesting to have the proposition of that book, French is also fine. (Haworth1977 refers to Kuratowski)

Comment: What do you mean by "says exactly the contrary"? If the product is finite the proposition says that the product is nowhere dense iff one of the elements of the product is nowhere dense.

Comment: @freakish correct, if we assume that $A$ is finite then, there is no contradiction. But in the text there is not such assumption, not even that $A$ is countable. I'm looking for a clear statement like 'If $A$ finite then', 'If $A$ countable then'

Comment: If you don't explain why you think it says exactly the contrary how can we answer this question? I guess it won't help if we just tell you that you are wrong, right?

Comment: @Yanko, see my last comment. I'm looking for a clear formulation.

Comment: Like that? (see my answer below)

Comment: @Yanko, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have the French edition of Topologie I, but page 154 does not have anything on products of nowhere dense sets.

Comment: @PeptideChain The finite case is easy and the last paragraph should explain why we need the extra condition in the infinite case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thank you, the exact reference by Haworth1977 is: *[36] Kuratowski, K., Topologie I, fourth ed., Warszawa 1958*, and in the text *[36], p. 154*. Then there should be an error in the reference.

Comment: That could well be. I have a facsimile edition of that book, bought in Paris. Errors in references do occur.

Comment: At some point it may be useful that $cl(\prod_{a\in A}N_a)\subset \prod_{a\in A}cl (N_a).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Which step do you have in mind? To begin, I need to show that int cl$\prod N_k\ne\varnothing$ (the product is somewhere dense) given that finitely many $N_k$ are somewhere dense. This proof is possible with your formula but with the inequality is replaced by the equality.

Comment: It is not generally an equality in infinite products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set. For all $\alpha\in A$ let $X_\alpha$ be a topological space and let $N_\alpha$ be a subset of $X_\alpha$.

**If $A$ is finite then**

> $\prod_{\alpha\in A} N_\alpha$ is nowhere dense in $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha$ if and only if there exists $\beta\in A$ such that $N_\beta$ is nowhere dense in $X_\beta$.

**If $A$ is infinite (countable or larger) then**

> $\prod_{\alpha\in A} N_\alpha$ is nowhere dense in $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha$ if and only if there exists $\beta\in A$ such that $N_\beta$ is nowhere dense in $X_\beta$ OR there exists infinitely many $\beta\in A$ such that the closure of $N_\beta$ is not $X_\beta$ (i.e. $N_\beta$ is not dense in $X_\beta$).

Note that if $A$ is finite then the condition "there exists infinitely many $\beta\in A$ such that..." can't be satisfied, so the second statement and the first statement are equivalent for finite $A$.

The main idea in this condition is that the product topology on a product space contains a "co-finite" cylinder set (it contains a product of all but finitely many of the $X_\alpha$) and so if the closure of $N_\beta$ is not $X_\beta$ for infinitely many $\beta$ then the closure of $\prod_{\alpha\in A} N_\alpha$ can't contain an open set.